# Rails 5 Active Record Associations

Tags: relational-database, rails-activerecord, foreign-key-relationship, ruby-on-rails-5

I am learning how to work with Ruby on Rails and want to find the best way to solve my issue.  I have searched through many forums and the Rails documentation, but haven't been able to understand a solution yet, so hoping someone might be able to help!

My app has 3 controllers- users, user_addresses, and invoices.  Each user can have multiple user_addresses, and also multiple invoices. I added a user_id column as a primary key for my user_addresses table and a user_id and address_id column as primary keys in my invoices table.

When I create an invoice and select an address to assign it to, then save it, I cannot figure out how to populate the both the user_id and address_id, I can only get one or the other to save.  In my example below I am getting the user_id to save, but not sure what to do to get both the user_id and id from the address to save to the invoice.

I have my User model set with has_many :user_addresses and has_many :invoices.  both my Invoice and UserAddress model belongs_to :user.  From what I have read, I think I may need to make use of a :through extension, but I am lost and not sure what to do.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

**Invoices Form**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:user_id, "Customer") %>
    <%= f.select(:user_id, @addresses.map {|a| [a.user.first_name + ' ' + a.user.last_name + ' - ' + a.street_1, a.user.id]},{}, {:class => 'form-control'})  %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
    <%= f.check_box(:status, :class => 'form-check-input')  %>
    Status
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:service_date, "Service Date") %>
    <%= f.text_field(:service_date, 'data-provide' => 'datepicker', :class => 'form-control')  %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:service_type, "Service Type") %>
    <%= f.select(:service_type, ["General Pest", "Weed Control", "Specialty Pest", "Rodent"],{}, {:class => 'form-control'})  %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= label_tag(:service_charge, "Service Charge") %>
    <%= f.text_field(:service_charge, :class => 'form-control')  %>
  </div>
```

**Invoices Controller**

```
  def new
    @invoice = Invoice.new
    @addresses = UserAddress.all
  end
```

**Invoices Table**

```
  create_table "invoices", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1" do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "address_id"
t.boolean  "status",            default: false
t.string   "service_date"
t.string   "service_type"
t.string   "service_areas"
t.string   "service_materials"
t.string   "service_charge"
t.string   "service_info"
t.datetime "created_at",                        null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                        null: false
t.index ["address_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_address_id", using: :btree
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_invoices_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

end

Comment: What does "I can only get one or the other to save" mean? Ie what input to what program causes what behaviour (errors and/or output) ? Also please show all relevant code & *read about [mcve]s*. PS See the edit I added at the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I added a user_id column as a primary key for my user_addresses table

Declaring that PK says that a user can have at most one address. If you want a user to be able to have multiple addresses then you don't want that PK. You probably want each user-address pair to be UNIQUE/PK.

> user_id and address_id column as primary keys in my invoices table

This means that you can't have two invoices for the same person-address pair. That's probably not what you want. Typically the only candidate/primary key for invoices is a unique runtime invoice id. Although it's quite likely you want *some kind of index* to help optimize finding invoices based on person-address pairs.

If you declare some columns as candidate key (possibly PK) then you are saying that they are unique and not NULL. But then you say that you want an invoice without having both a user and address, which contradicts that. There are many invoices per user, but only because there are many user-address pairs (each with an invoice) per user. Declare that such a *pair* has an invoice. And not that a user does, because you would have to keep UserInvoice redundantly in sync with Invoice. (But really you want invoice ids.)

A :through manages that redundancy. Including addressing the indexing optimization mentioned above.

Read about first making a relational design then expressing it (and desired optimizations) via an Active Record design.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I may have not explained thoroughly but I do want all invoices to have a user_id and address_id... But since users can have multiple addresses, I cannot figure out how to set up the relation to automatically populate the db based off selection. I will do some more research about relational design via Active Record.  I did find a solution through setting a data-attr on the  select field options set to the address id and the using jQuery to fill the value of a hidden form element to submit the address id to the form.

Comment: I didn't say an invoice wouldn't have an associated user_id & address_id. I said that you probably wanted those not to form a CK of Invoices and you probably wanted a column invoice_id that did.